# Closest, index and minimum distance between points

Tags: python, scipy

I have a code that calculates the distance between closest points in a list, by using cdist.

However, I would like an improved version also gives me the index of the **Points**.

```
    distance.cdist(Coordinates,Points).min(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) instead.

<sub>( padding)</sub>